# Label distance in polar chart is not equal on each angle

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Who's gonna tell me, how to make correction of label positioning depends on value and angle in Highcharts Polar chart?
Please take a look at pictures:

**Example 1:** Here you can see, that angle values are displayed on bottom half is not positioned well - labels aren't have so much distance from the circle of outer graph line like the top ones.

[image: Polar Chart with startAngle = 0]

**Example 2:** Angle values labels are displayed like they are moved a little bit to the right and labels at down is moved up a little bit too - the same as in example 1.

[image: Polar Chart with startAngle = 210]

I'm using library **Highstock v5.0.12.** and here is fragment of my js code:

```
xAxis: {
  tickInterval: 30,
  min: 0,
  max: 360,
  labels: {
      formatter: function() {
          return this.value + '°';
      },
      style: {
          "fontSize": "1.1vw",
      },
      distance: 15,
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating solution using documented example and updating with existing code.

Solution is to update with `useHTML` and `align` property

```
xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 30,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value + '°';
      },
      style: {
        "fontSize": "1.1vw",
      },
      distance: 15,
      useHTML: true,  
      align: 'center' 
    }
  },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66a1btpu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can you `xAxis.labels.y` option for this:

```
labels: {
  y: 6,
  formatter: function() {
    return this.value + '°';
  },
  style: {
    fontSize: '20px'
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/36k19Lhp/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.y